# What is the equivalent to --help or man page in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, command-line-arguments

If I want to know what my options are for a Linux program then I'll do `man program` or `program --help` to find out. How do you do that on Windows?

I was reading about how to run a screensaver from the command line and I found out about this file:

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\scrnsave.scr
```

When called directly, the settings page for that screensaver is launched instead of the actual screensaver.

I tried `help scrnsave.scr` and `scrnsave.scr /?` and more, but nothing worked. It wasn't until I tried google that I found the [command line options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686421.aspx#ss_cmdline) in the middle of a MSDN article and knew I had to use:

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\scrnsave.scr /s
```

How was I supposed to know about the /s option? What is the correct way to find program options in the Windows command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There *isn't* a correct way.  But there isn't on Unix, either.  The `--help` convention is in fact a **GNU** convention.  It's widespread on Linux distributions, where the operating system utilities are GNU ones.  But you won't see it in the operating system utilities on a BSD, for example:

```
$ /bin/sh --help
Illegal option --
$ nawk --help
nawk: no program given

$
```

Much as the `--help` convention has been seen by many as a good idea, and adopted; the `/?` convention (which originated in DR-DOS 5.0 as a `/H` convention) has been seen by many as a good idea, and adopted.  You'll find that many commands support it.  But equally as not all commands in Unix or Linux support `--help` not all commands in DOS or Windows NT support `/?`.

You might think that `man` comes to the rescue here.  Thanks to GNU `info`, and the fact that several program maintainers seem to place information (even sometimes information as basic as what the command-line options are) only in the `info` page and not in the `man` page or vice versa, it's not the panacaea that it might be thought to be, however.

`man` doesn't really have an equivalent in the DOS and Windows NT world.  The closest equivalent was `help`*command*, which in DR-DOS 5.0 and later and MS-DOS 6.0 and later would look up *command* in a database of help pages and display the page.  The problem here is that whilst all of the operating system's own housekeeping utilities had pages in this database, almost no-one else's programs did, and the system was hard to add third-party information to.

(DOSBook, introduced in DR-DOS 6.0 was about the best that any commercial DOS got with this.  MS-DOS used QuickHelp files, the tool for compiling which wasn't supplied with the base operating system.  PC-DOS 7 had the IPF system, a tool for compiling which again was lacking from the operating system.  OS/2 had the same IPF system as PC-DOS, and a HELP command that was integrated with it, although again the compiler, IPFC, was in the Developers Toolkit rather than in the box with the operating system.  Many years ago I wrote [an improvement upon the supplied HELP command](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/Softwares/clu.html#help) where one could configure which command reference**s** it looked commands up in by default, with an environment variable.  I also provided an extended command reference book for some commands that I'd written.)

Windows NT still has `help`*command* to this day.  It's a step backwards from what MS-DOS 6 had, let alone from what DR-DOS, PC-DOS, and OS/2 had.

So the actual answer is: *You're supposed to trawl through MSDN, or read someone else's WWW site, or read a book, or read the source code (if it's open source), or just know telepathically …*

That said, documentation on the WWW is not a bad thing, and is largely the expectation nowadays.  (Although one can miss things like IPFC building indexes and tables of contents for one.  ☺)  Microsoft documents a whole raft of command-line commands on TechNet and in MSDN, as you have seen.

### Further reading

- [*4.7 Standards for Command Line Interfaces*](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Command_002dLine-Interfaces).  GNU Coding Standards.  Free Software Foundation.
- [*Customizing DOSBook*](http://www.drdos.net/documentation/custdb/index.htm).  Caldera.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard. [*HELPMSG*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/Softwares/cmd/commands/helpmsg.html).  32-bit Command Interpreter command reference.
- [*HELP*](http://jpsoft.com/help/help.htm).  TCC/LE command reference.  JP Software.
- [*IPF Programming Guide and Reference*](http://cyberkinetica.homeunix.net/os2tk45/ipfref/).  OS/2 Warp 4.5 Developers' Toolkit.  IBM.
- [*Windows XP Command line reference A–Z*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx).  TechNet.  Microsoft corporation.

Comment: powershell provides a little bit better documentation via the `man` alias

Answer (score 10):

For pure Windows programs, displaying help is usually `/?`. However, there are more and more cross-platform programs coming up and they use `-?`, `--help` or even other commands.

Actually it's not required by Windows programs to support any help output at all, so it's all up to the developer of the program.

Screensavers are a little bit special, because Microsoft has defined what a screensaver has to support. And what you found it exactly that definition Obviously Microsoft does not define any mandatory `/?` command line switch.